# How to pass object as parameter via <portlet:param> in one jsp page and retrieve in other jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

On page A.jsp I have an object which I want to pass to page B.jsp.

**A.jsp**

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("organization", organization); //the second parameter organization is the object.

<portlet:renderURL var="addOrganizationURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/organization/B.jsp" />
    <portlet:param name="organization" value="${organization}" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

I set the attribute `string organization` to the `object organization`. And then pass it as the `<portlet:param>`.

**B.jsp**

```
renderRequest.getParameter("organization") //This obviously returns the string of the format {organizationId=, acronym=, name=, url=,  description=, backup=false, trainingCourses=false}

renderRequest.getAttribute("organization") //This returns the null object
```

The `string` is not what I want. What I want is to be able to get the `object organization` itself so that I can invoke the methods on that object. Like `organization.getName(), organization.getUrl().`

Comment: You can only pass string as parameter. You may like to pass orgnizationId and then get organization by organizationId in render method and set it in request attribute

Comment: I was doing the same way. Passing organizationId as a portlet parameter and retrieving it on the other page. Did not know that you can only pass string as parameter. Actually I did not like to query again on the another page with this organizationId and hence was looking for passing object as parameter instead.